# rosjava ChannelBuffer parameter

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I updated rosjava today (July 27th) and am now getting a compilation error in a node that creates an OccupancyGrid message.

The method setData in the OccupancyGrid class used to have a byte[] parameter, but the parameter is now a ChannelBuffer.

How do I create a ChannelBuffer with my occupancy grid data?

ChannelBuffer looks like an internal class and not one that should be a  parameter to a public method.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39967/rosjava-channelbuffer-parameter/) by [LawrieGriffiths](https://answers.ros.org/users/1997/lawriegriffiths/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can read up more on Channel Buffer accessors [here](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffer.html) and about creating channel buffers [here](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffers.html)

Depending on your code, there might be more efficient methods of initializing the channel buffer. If your byte[] array is already prepared, you could do something as simple as:

```
ChannelBuffer buffer = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(byte_array);
```

ChannelBuffer is not an internal class. rosjava maintainers should be able to answer better as to why byte arrays were changed to this.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-08-01**:
Providing ChannelBuffers directly is more performant and they provide a useful interface for working with blobs.